# Newcommand for table

Tags: tables, macros

I have to use certain table format again and again, so I decided to create a new command for better tex file readability. Table as such works but when I put a working table header then it gives me a error. Here is the code

```
\newcommand{\Vigrah}[3]{
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{#1}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{13cm}|}
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
लौकिक    & {#2} \\
अलौकिक & {#3} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
}
```

I was calling this by \Vigrah{Name }{text 1}{ text 2} what am I doing wrong. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Can you please add a complete minimal example showing the problem? Your snippet (after suitable completion) works OK in my system.

Answer (score 2):

This works OK (with an overfull `\hbox` warning due to the table width being biiger than the default text width):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003}

\newcommand{\Vigrah}[4]{
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{#1}
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{13cm}}
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
लौकिक    & {#2} \\
अलौकिक & {#3} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:#4}%
\end{table}%
}

\begin{document}

\Vigrah{Name}{Text 1}{Text 2}{label}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I added a fourth argument to have different unique labels for the tables; I also suppressed the vertical rules (`booktabs` and vertical rules don't play well together).

Comment: Thats great, I have a mypackage.sty file I was putting this in that file and it gave me error, but instead now I put in header just before begin document and it worked. I wonder why.

Comment: @Raama probably a conflict between the package and some other definition(s); hard to tell without the actual code. If you want to, you can upload that package elsewhere and leave a link here in a comment, so I can take a look and see where the problem might be.